# Python 3.x nested loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried this nested while loop and I'm not getting the expected answer.

```
ctr = 0
ctr1 = 0
while ctr<4:
    while ctr1<4:
        print(ctr,ctr1)
        ctr1 = ctr1+1
    ctr = ctr+1
```

Comment: So, what answer did you expect?

Comment: i was expecting-  11,12,13,21,22,23,31,32,33 on a newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably made a mistake with is:

```
ctr = 0
while ctr<4:
    ctr1 = 0 ### Reset every loop
    while ctr1<4:
        print(ctr,ctr1)
        ctr1 = ctr1+1
    ctr = ctr+1
```

BTW, a more idiomatic way is:

```
for ctr in range(4):
    for ctr1 in range(4):
        print(ctr, ctr1)
```